# Read byte array in Android using k-soap2

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays, ksoap2

I'm using this code in .net web service to send image as byte array:

```
public byte[] getImage()
{
    byte[] img;
    ....
    return img;
}
```

How can read this byte array using ksoap2 and convert it to bitmap?

Can you explain that in simple code.

Update:
This code I'm using in android to read data from web service:

```
        String SOAP_ACTION = WebServiceNameSpace + GetImage;
        String NAMESPACE = WebServiceNameSpace;
        String METHOD_NAME = GetImage;
        String URL = WS_URL;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope Envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        Envelope.dotNet = true;
        Envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, Envelope);
        SoapPrimitive primetive = (SoapPrimitive) Envelope.getResponse();
        return primetive.toString();
```

Comment: Do you have the web service client for your android app already, or you have trouble receiving the data too?

Comment: yes I have web service, and I have android code using SoapObject to receive data from this web service, but I don't know how to revive byte[] datatype

Comment: Please share your service consuming java code too, so we can help your working from that.

Comment: The web service built on .net, my problem in android side

Comment: Please look to above update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you have consumed the web service successfully, and retrieved the bytes, all you need to do is to decode the data and retrieve the `Bitmap` from it:

```
final SoapPrimitive primitive = (SoapPrimitive) Envelope.getResponse();
final String imgData = primitive.toString();
if (imgData != "") 
{
    byte[] imgBytes = Base64.decode(imgData, Base64.DEFAULT);         
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length);
    // TODO: set this bitmap into an ImageView or handle it as you wish
}
```

If you have issues with the decoding part, please refer to [this answer and its links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6807664/506879) too.

Comment: Thanks a lot rekaszeru, that is what I need :)